# Per Mark 1:4, Luke 3:3 why did John the Baptist preach the "baptism of repentance" and not "repent" for the forgivness of sin?

Tags: luke, acts, mark, john-the-baptist

John the Baptist never told any one to directly repent of their sin. He preached the "baptism of repentance" for the forgiveness of sin. Is there a significant difference in the two concepts?


> Mark 1:4: John did baptize in the wilderness, and preached the baptism
>   of repentance for the remission of sins.



> Luke 3:3: And he came into all the country about Jordan, preaching the
>   baptism of repentance for the remission of sins;



> Acts 13:24: When John had first preached before his coming the baptism
>   of repentance to all the people of Israel.
>
> Acts 19:4: Then said Paul, John verily baptized with the baptism of
>   repentance, saying unto the people, that they should believe on him
>   which should come after him, that is, on Christ Jesus.

All verses KJV.

Comment: Μετανοια _metanoia_ (a matter of the mind and a matter of the powerful linguistic tool μετα) is 'unto' (it is εις) the aphesis of sins. Metanoia, itself, does not bring the unburdening of aphesis. But it leads to it. The process is intimate and all enveloping, which is why water immersion is used to express it's occurrence.

Comment: In Mt. 3:2, John actually says: "Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand." Can you explain the essential difference between preaching baptism of repentance for the remission of sins and directly repent of their sin? And Mt. 3:8...., John specifically says "bear fruit in keeping with repentance."  And how is it that the Matthews accounts is NOT cited?

Answer (score 1):

John was Baptizing repentance for sins they had done against the Mosaic Law as a way to prepair the Jewish people for The Messiah, Jesus:-

> Luke 3:3, 4  NWT "So he went into all the country around the Jordan, preaching baptism in symbol of repentance for forgiveness of sins, 4 just as it is written in the book of the words of Isaiah the prophet: “A voice of one crying out in the wilderness: ‘Prepare the way of Jehovah! Make his roads straight.

Vs 4 show that the way of the People had taken was not right according to "the book"; a refferance to The Bible; and they had to get "straight" with God to meet The Messiah who was about to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

> John the Baptist never told any one to directly repent of their sin.

Bewildering that you would make such an assertion. The first occurrence of the verb μετάνω, often translated as “repent,” occurs in Mark 3:2 and has John the Baptist commanding people to repent.

> <sup>1</sup> In those days, John the Baptist came preaching in the wilderness of Judaea, <sup>2</sup> and saying, “**Repent**, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand!”
>
> <sup>Αʹ</sup> ἐν δὲ ταῖς ἡμέραις ἐκείναις παραγίνεται Ἰωάννης ὁ βαπτιστὴς κηρύσσων ἐν τῇ ἐρήμῳ τῆς Ἰουδαίας <sup>Βʹ</sup> καὶ λέγων **μετανοεῖτε** ἤγγικεν γὰρ ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν

Comment: Ah, but here's the issue. I never said John didn't say repent.  The word repent means just to change your mind. You must look to the context to find what to change your mind about. Hence the issue with the doctrine of repentance. Most people "assume" when they hear the word repent, it means to repent of your sin; context must tell you how to repent. For example, in Mark 1:14-15, John says "repent and believe the gospel"; change your mind and believe the gospel. If you link that with other verses like Hebrews 6:1, you get a different perspective on repentance.

Comment: Understood. That being said, repentance involves confessing one's sins. That is the initial stage of repentance. One cannot sincerely repent until he acknowledges and confesses his sins. (see Matt. 3:2 cp. Matt. 3:6)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that many people need help to repent. There is power in unity.

> Mat 18:19 (NIV) “Again, truly I tell you that if two of you on earth agree about anything they ask for, it will be done for them by my Father in heaven".

John, through his water baptism, acted as a paraclete (advocate, helper) for the purpose of facilitating breakthroughs for honest repenters, people who were struggling with spiritual strongholds.

Answer (score 0):

Bible writers display a large array of terms to cover what theologians call "atonement".  Sometimes I think we get a little hung up on our particular favourite term for this or that.  The Christian experience involves, prompting by the Holy Spirit, a recognition of one's sinfulness, a confession, a repentance, a conversion, a new life, and a growing into Christ, etc, etc.  While most of these are modern terms, the Bible writers were not nearly so constrained and used many of these terms rather loosely, plus many more.  Here is a sample of rich atonement language of which John's was part.  Therefore, I do not think we should be too precise about how Bible authors describe these abstract ideas.

- Christ’s robe of righteousness provided a covering to hide the sinner’s wretched state.  Job 29:14, Ps 132:9, Isa 11:5, 59:17, 61:10, 64:6, Zech 3:4, 5, Matt 22:1-14 (wedding garment parable), Rev 3:4, 6:11, 7:9, 19:8.  This robe is a counterpoint to the “filthy rags” of Isa 64:6 and Zech 3:4, and immediately and completely hides them.
- The Greek verb “aphiemi”, to forgive or give remission, means (literally) to send forth or send away.  It is used of sins in Matt 9:2, 5, 6, 12:31, 32, 26:28, Mark 14:24, Acts 8:22, Rom 4:7, James 5:12, 1 John 1:9, 2:12, etc.  That is, our sins are sent away or banished.  See also Mark 3:29, Acts 5:31, 13:38, 26:18, Eph 1:7, Col 1:14.  Again, Jesus accomplished this great work on the cross.
- Propitiation or expiation (Greek: “hilasterion”) denotes the act of appeasing a deity by sacrifice to incur divine favour (it is only an analogue, metaphor or figure of speech!).  Thus, Jesus’ sacrifice is described as propitiation in Rom 3:25 and 1 John 2:2.  These are direct references to the same word used in the Septuagint in Ex 25:17-22 (and repeated in Heb 9:5) where the “atonement cover” or “mercy seat” of the Ark of the Covenant is described.  That is, the covering of the Ark provided both atonement and mercy at the same time!  See also 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Pet 3:18.  Thus, Jesus is correctly described as “the lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world.” (John 1:29, 36).
- Justify and Justification (Greek cognate root: “dike”) means to pronounce righteous or acquit and is obviously a legal term.  Paul, in Romans, tells us that God has freely justified all sinners (Rom 3:23-27) and that this occurred while we were still sinners (Rom 5:5, 8, 9) by His death on the cross.  This “declaring right” is clearly what God does and is His initiative and something that cannot be earned (Rom 3:20).  In Gal 2:16 we are emphatically told that we are justified by trusting God and not by works of the law.  It is often used inter-changeably with “Credit”, see below.
- The Bible also uses the idea of Jesus’ death being a kind of penal substitutionary execution to satisfy the requirements of “the law”; thus, His death was an essential part of our salvation.  Isa 53:5, 6, 11, 12, Matt 20:28, Rom 5:19, 2 Cor 5:21, Gal 1:4, 3:13, Heb 9:15.  Again, the extent to which this is literally true is highly debated – is it only a metaphor to demonstrate God’s great love and grace?  Or did Jesus’ death actually change something about God’s attitude to us (recall that Jesus is also God!)  Obviously Jesus’ death did not change God’s mind because God gave His Son and God did not give something in order to change His own mind!  Jesus death was to demonstrate His justice (Rom 3:22-28).
- In Rev 12:7-10 the process that leads to atonement is depicted as a war which Jesus wins.  His victory obtains atonement for mankind (Col 2:15, 1 Peter 3:22).  In this warfare, sinners are God’s enemies that He must capture in the war (Rom 5:10).  This metaphor is extended for the Christian life (Eph 6:10-17, 1 Thess 5:8) with “the armour of God”.
- “Credit”, “account”, “imputed”, or “reckoned” (Greek: logizomai) is a financial or accounting term used in the market place but was employed by Paul to denote the act of God in crediting Abraham (and sinners generally) as righteous when they trusted in God, apart from the works of the law, as a free gift.  The idea is based upon the assumption that sin creates a debt to God which must be repaid (Col 2:13-15, Matt 6:12).  Again, it is only an analogue, metaphor or figure of speech and so is not literally true.  (Rom 4:3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 22, 23, 24, 2 Cor 5:19, Gal 3:6, James 2:23.  (See also Gen 15:6.)  That is, the righteousness of God is “imputed” to the underserving sinner, freely.  Thus, God “cancels the debt” (Matt 18:21-35).
- “Gift” is used to convey the idea that atonement is absolutely free and the initiative of God.  Rom 4:4, 5:15-17, 6:23, 2 Cor 9:14, 15, Eph 2:8, 3:7, Heb 6:4.
- Redemption, Ransom, or most correctly, Manumission:  Two Greek words are translated “redeem” (“exagerazo” and “lutroo”) with almost exactly equivalent meanings.  Both speak of Christ redeeming sinners as slaves (Luke 1:68, 24:21) by paying a ransom (Matt 20:28, Mark 10:45, 1 Tim 2:6, Heb 9:15), but, Scripture is silent about to whom the manumission fee was paid (it is only an analogue, metaphor or figure of speech!).  1 Cor 6:20, 7:23, Gal 3:13, 4:5, Titus 2:14, 1 Peter 1:18, Rev 5:9.  This manumission idea emphasises God’s free gift of salvation because both Greek verbs were commonly used to buy freedom for a slave or hostage, without any contribution of the slave.  Perhaps the most touching example of redemption is contained in the enacted parable of Hosea and Gomer – see Hosea 3:1-3.  The New Testament also presents several things from which the sinner needs freedom: (a) Freedom from the devil, Heb 2:14, 15, (b) Freedom from death, 1 Cor 15:56, 57, (c) Freedom from the power of sin that enslaves, Rom 6:22, (d) Freedom from the condemnation of the law, Rom 3:19-24, Gal 3:13, 4:5
- Reconciliation describes the process of reuniting an estranged family member.  It is predicated on two Biblical assumptions that (a) Jesus is our brother (Heb 2:11-13, Ps 22:22, Isa 8:17, 18, Matt 12:48, 49, John 20:17, Rom 8:29), and (b) sin separates us from Jesus our brother (Isa 59:2, Gal 5:4, Eph 2:12, Ps 22:1, Eze 14:5, Jer 6:8).  Reconciliation is found in only a few places but they, again, emphasise that atonement is God’s initiative without any input from us.  In 2 Cor 5:18, 19 we find that Christ reconciled the world to Himself by “not counting our sins against us”.  Rom 5:10, 11 teaches that sinners were reconciled to God by Christ’s death.  Further, a comparison with v9 shows that justification and reconciliation are used in parallel.
- Rescue (save):  The Greek verb, “sozo” means literally to rescue or deliver from danger (Matt 8:25, Mark 13:20, Luke 23:35, John 12:27, 1 Tim 2:15, 2 Tim 4:18).  Thus, when the New Testament discusses salvation, it is using the figure of someone in immanent mortal danger being rescued by a “rescuer” (Acts 2:47, 16:31, Rom 8:24, Eph 2:5, 8, 1 Tim 2:4, 2 Tim 19, Titus 3:5, etc).  This a perfect figure of our relationship with Jesus who delivers us from the danger of sin (Phil 2:12) and eternal loss (Rom 13:11, 1 Thess 5:8, 9 2 Thess 2:13, Heb 1:14, 9:28, 1 Peter 1:5, 2 Peter 3:15, etc).  See also Eph 6:17 where salvation is described as a helmet to protect from spiritual danger.  This figure also emphasises that salvation must come from outside the person.
- The absolving of sin is sometimes represented as a “washing away” of sin, or “cleansing”.  Lev 16:30, Num 19:9, Ps 51:2, 7, 10, Isa 4:4, Eze 36:25, Zech 13:1, 1 Cor 6:10, Eph 5:26, 1 John 1:7, 9.  The practice of Baptism is built on this vivid metaphor and thus depicted as washing away of sin (Acts 22:16) as well as death to the old life and resurrection to a new life in Christ.
- Adoption can also be a figure of atonement.  In this case the metaphor serves both as a figure of the change of life and of the privileges of being adopted into a “royal” family of God.

It will be readily observed that these metaphors often overlap, and, more than one is used in some passages.  Thus, it often appears that Bible writers struggled to express an abstract idea in more concrete terms using multiple metaphors.

Answer (score 0):

What is the dofference between John preached the “baptism of repentance for the remission of sins” against Heb. 9:22 "....without sheding of the blood there is no remission of sins..." ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a significant difference between the phrases “the baptism of repentance for the forgiveness of sins” and “repent for the forgiveness of sins”.

The former statement is:

- God oriented
- grace oriented (a gift)
- 100% God’s action through the Holy Spirit

The latter statement is:

- man oriented
- work oriented
- 100% man’s action through self effort

With respect to baptism, you cannot baptize yourself. The Holy Spirit must come upon you. John the Baptist was very clear, in that his call to the Jews to “repent” was via the **baptism of** repentance where the effort is NOT something that man musters up within himself and then offers to God. No, John’s exhortation was a call for man to receive the grace of God, the free gift of God via the Holy Spirit and exercise of his faith.

John preached the “baptism of repentance for the forgiveness of sins” and NOT “repent for the forgiveness of sins”.